# How can the data of this script element be accessed?

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to access some metadata on a page.

Some `script` elements can be accessed, but seemingly not one in particular.

For example:

```
response = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/br/olympia-residence.en-gb.html", verify=False).content, "html.parser")

scriptData = response.select('script[type="text/javascript"]')
```

In the HTML, there is a script element with a `window.utag_data` variable, but `scriptData` only contains data from another `script` element.

I thought that the particular `script` element's absence may be due to it being loaded dynamically on the page, but if that's the case, I couldn't narrow down what response was delivering that data.

Is it possible to get the `window.utag_data` with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the website is sending a different HTML depending on how you access the request.

I can see `window.utag_data` if I access that page from the browser, but not if I fetch it with curl:

```
$ curl -s https://www.booking.com/hotel/br/olympia-residence.en-gb.html | grep utag_data
$
```

It also doesn't show in the response downloaded with the code you provided:

```
>>> 'window.utag_data' in str(response)
False
```

You can try to replay the request as if it were done by a browser (e.g. using a browser user agent).

Comment: Although I thought that it may have been due to the script data being dynamic, your answer made encouraged me to test a different method which apparently worked (using a query and header with the "GET" method; I'll likely post as an answer tomorrow). If I'm wrong, please correct me; My current understanding is that data can be determined to be dynamic if it doesn't load when turning javascript off in the browser.

Comment: ...and I assume you don't mean use a browser emulator by "browser user agent'. If you get a chance and can clarify (unless that's the method I used that worked), I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Phillip I just meant setting some HTTP headers so that the request is a bit more similar to what it looks like as if it were a browser. It seems that setting the User-agent and the Accept-language HTTP headers when sending the request works: `curl -s 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/br/olympia-residence.en-gb.html' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36' | grep utag_data`

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanation. Also, a query string ended up not being needed.